# Rechargeable battery vs Alkaline

Tags: batteries

I make custom clocks, some of these with electromechanical control circuits.  An example would be a cuckoo clock that has a small dc motor / drive circuit used to actuate a bird/door mechanism.  Although not explictly forbidden by the manufacturer, I've had customers substitute the normal 'AA" sized alkalines with a rechargeable variety and now have had a couple of issues come up that may / may not be related to this configuration.

A couple of observations about these mechanisms when driven with the rechargeables - The magnetically driven pendulum has a noticeable difference in amplitude ie much larger swing arc.
- the bird drive mechanism appears to actuate more "crisply", the drive motor appears to have an increased rpm as it drives the  worm gear actuator.

One of these cuckoo units have failed, and it is something in the drive circuitry that has apparently died a bit at a time - eg. the cuckoo would drive in one direction and not the other. Pulling the batteries and resetting the unit and it would start up again - but ultimately exhibited the same failure and died altogether.
Is there an operational issue with the voltages / current profile with rechargeables that might explain this failure mode?  Customers resist the idea that the batteries might be causing the issue as the are the same "voltage" and sold on the idea of "plug compatibility".  Any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thanks.

I appreciate the quick replies - with limited knowledge on the subject I can't fill in the technical questions in too much more details - assuming that the operational cycle has repeatable power draw, woud the device require more current if the available voltage is lower in the rechargeables?  And if so, would the driving circuit take a hit?

Comment: We'd need more information about the specs of the rechargeable type. However, this issue requires careful elimination of variables as the causes and it's almost impossible for us to answer with the information provided and without seeing the device.

Comment: Actually, alkaline and rechargeables are **not** the same voltage.  However, the rechargeable chemistries tend to have a lower voltage than the alkalines, so that does not seem to explain the differences you have seen.  What might be an explanation is that the rechargeables might be "better" cells with lower internal impedance - if the mechanism draws "unreasonable" amounts of current when in operation, low quality cells might tend to drop in voltage under load and that be what normally limits the speed of operation, causing cells which can hold up under such load to run it atypically fast.

Comment: I appreciate the quick replies - with limited knowledge on the subject I can't fill in the technical questions in too much more details - assuming that the operational cycle has repeatable power draw, woud the device require more current if the available voltage is lower in the rechargeables? And if so, would the driving circuit take a hit?

Answer (score 0):

In general the lower voltages of rechargeable batteries (1.2 vs 1.5 volts) causes problems in many devices. Some digital camera models are very sensitive to voltage and will not work or only take a few pictures before needing a recharged battery. Have you tried putting fresh alkaline batteries in the failed unit? I have had very good results using zinc/nickel NIZN 1.6 volt rechargeable  batteries. You can buy 4 with an NIZN charger for about $20 dollars online. They are the best batteries for both my cameras and handheld GPS, and I have had good results for years.